# What is Fast&Easy way to migrate Flex 3.5/4 Web App to Flash Builder 4.6 for Mobile iOS?

Tags: ios, spring, apache-flex, migration, builder

I currently have a fully working web app built in Flex 3.5/4 using java back end with Spring Framework using TomCat.

I need to migrate or convert this project into Flash Builder 4.6 to create a mobile iOS application and use the same SpringFramework with TomCat. How can i do this?

1. Do i just copy code over and adjust?
2. Do I export from flex 3.5/4 and import into flash builder 4.6 and adjust for mobile?
3. Is there a certain export feature that exports to mobile?
4. Do I have to change the code to mobile components by hand? Is there anything automated?

I have spent about 3 days trying to search and figure out specific detailed information on what to do, but oddly enough, I have not found anything that is helpful. I say it is ODD because Adobe claims that with Flash Builder 4.6 and 4.7, migrating to different platforms, will remove about 70% of the work with the latest Flash Builder. However, I have found no tutorials or steps on exactly what to do. I don't even know if the spring framework would work with TomCat for an iOS app.

Here's what I have found out through my research:
1. Migrating to mobile, I will have to change various code to use the mobile optimized components for performance.

What do I need to do?

EDIT: I even tried adding mx.swc to my library path just for testing purposes to make things easier for the migration/conversion and it still doesn't fix my error in Flash Builder 4.6 mobile project with mx:Application:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFdIk.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Lots of things to cover; and I'm not sure where to start.  First, I want to clarify that the browser based app you developed for a 72-ish dpi 15+ inch computer screen may not easily migrate to 3.5/4 inch iPhone or 9.7 inch iPad screen. Keeping that in mind

> ```
> Do i just copy code over and adjust?
> ```

I would start there, yes.  Even better if you move the 'shared' code into a library project so you can use it for your web app and your mobile project.  Flex 3.5 does not formally have mobile support; so I would not expect great performance on a mobile device.  You'll also have to add some "non-mobile optimized" libraries to the library path manually in a Flash Builder Mobile project.  The MX.swc is probably the big one, as you already mentioned.

> ```
> Do I export from flex 3.5/4 and import into flash builder 4.6 and adjust for mobile?
> ```

In Flash Builder 4.6 mobile projects are different than web projects.  Most likely you'll want to move as much shared code as possible into a library project and then create a web project--for maintenance of your current application--and a mobile project for deployment to iOS and other mobile devices.

> ```
> Is there a certain export feature that exports to mobile?
> ```

If you have created a Flash Builder Mobile project; then yes you can export to iOS, Android, or Blackberry.

> ```
> Do I have to change the code to mobile components by hand? Is there anything automated?
> ```

Yes, you'll have to change code to mobile components by hand.  That is if you are replacing a non-mobile optimized component with a mobile optimized one.  However, if you are using a Spark Component [introduced in Flex 4], such as a List, then you can use the spark list with the default theme in the web project and a spark list with the mobile theme in your mobile project without any changes.

> ...Adobe claims that with Flash Builder 4.6 and 4.7, migrating to
>   different platforms, will remove about 70% of the work with the latest
>   Flash Builder.

I am not aware of such claims.  But, I do believe that you can reuse a lot of code between mobile projects and non-mobile projects.  It took me 3-4 months to build a mobile game using AIR/Flex.  It took me less than a day to port the code to work in a web browser.

> I don't even know if the spring framework would work with TomCat for
>   an iOS app.

If you want you're iOS app to make calls to a server, then yes it will work without issues.
If you want to deploy Tomcat and Spring onto an iOS device I would not expect that to work.

This question is a bit non-specific; but I tried to help.  If that doesn't point you in a direction, then I may ask what have you tried and what problems have you run into?

Comment: thanks for the answers. As for the TomCat and SpringFramework questions, yes I will be making calls to a server. Does it work the same way as how my web app is done? I was not the person to set up the connections between flex, spring, the server and tomcat so I am very unfamiliar how they communicate exactly. 

Can I just duplicate the way the web application connects and do the same for my mobile app? (With the mobile app being the client and sending data requests and such to the server where TomCat is running)?

I couldn't find any help on setting up TomCat with Spring for mobile support

Comment: I just converted one of my .mxml web application file to the mobile version that is successfully compiling. Right now my problem is getting the mobile app to work with my oracle sql database to use the same procedures, triggers and tables already made for the web application.

Comment: Connecting your UI to the server is no different on a mobile app vs a non-mobile app.  Your UI code is probably one layer removed from your Oracle Database. I'd guess the app never accesses the database directly, but does so through services built in Tomcat.  It would be highly unusual to do use a different approach.

Comment: The setup is different and thats where my problem is. I don't know how to set up the connectivity between my UI to the server. I also cannot debug my java code that is in my flash builder 4.6 mobile project. Do you have any idea how?

Comment: I'm not sure what setup is different nor what it is different from. Connectivity between your UI and server is no different when building a mobile Flex app vs building a non-mobile Flex app.  I like to have different Eclipse projects for UI code and server side code.

Comment: I copy and imported everything from my Flex,java Web App to my mobile. and converted enough so that it can compile. However, it is not communicating with the database at all or doesnt seem like its connecting to my TomCat. If nothing is different, then why doesnt the mobile app just simply connect, when I copy exactly what was in my WebApp to my mobile app as far as the web.xml file, applicationContext.xml file and the other -config.xml files.

Comment: Without reviewing your code; or knowing how you're connecting; I can't tell you what is different.  Flex can communicate with the backend with REST (via HTTPService), or AMF (Via RemoteObject) or SOAP (via WebService).  Are you receiving errors?  Have you tried debugging your app with breakpoints? Have you tried watching the network packets w/ a tool such as the Flash Builder Network Monitor? Have you checked compiler arguments between the two projects for missing services-config files and/or libraries?

Comment: yes i tried debugging but don't know how to get to the JAVA side of debugging with flash builder. I think the java side is server based as it asks for a port and hostname which I set up exactly like the web app project. It doesn't debug into the java code which communicates using RemoteObject, using the service, BO, DAO structure. Compiler arguments are the same for both. Since the mobile app doesn't have a war file, I don't know what to do either  in that area because with the web app, i exported a war file into the root folder and just relaunched TomCat.

Comment: That would automatically extract and launch your new changes and then i would just do the 'Validate Configuration' in eclipse and then run. and if i want to debug into java i would start the debug java server.

All this seems different with the mobile app and I am DEEPLY surprised there are no tutorials, help or anything that involves configuring a mobile app that was converted from a web app from Flex to Flash Builder connecting to an Oracle SQL database.